# Why does the process which creates the postgis extension hang?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-extensions

While executing the command "create extension postgis;" I see that the psql process hangs indefinitely and the only information that strace gives me is that its stuck in this indefinite futex call `futex(0x2ac7aac6928c, FUTEX_WAIT, 1, NULL` I can't seem to figure out what's the issue that's leading to this hung process. Would appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Probably waiting on a lock, check `pg_locks`

Comment: sure lemme check that